# return text for cat /proc/PID/status is in binary

Tags: linux, solaris

I am trying to get data returned in the same format as this example i found regarding /proc:

```
$ cat /proc/$$/status
Name:   bash
Umask:  0022
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   17248
Ngid:   0
Pid:    17248
PPid:   17200
...
```

when I run the command however I get a binary text dump like so

```
^@^@0^@^@^@^A^@^@W8^@^@B        ^@^@W8^@^@B     ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^P^Y<E0>^@^@^@^@^@^H<E6> <FF><FF><FF><FF>^?<FF>^
```

Is there a way to get this data converted into parsable text? I am working on a solaris 11 server if that is important.

Comment: There are [various commands that begin with `p`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/proc-1.html) which will return some of the process info in text, but Solaris and Linux don’t have all the same info in the same files. Can you give us a list of the data you need?

Comment: Do we talk about Solaris or Linux?